# MySQL query to unique combination of columns

Tags: mysql

Table-

```
TestID | IntegID
=======|======
P1     | In1
P2     | In2
P2     | In2
P3     | In3
P1     | In5
P1     | In5
P2     | In2
P3     | In3
P2     | In9
```

Output desired:

```
TestID | IntegID
=======|======
P1     | In1
P1     | In5
P2     | In2
P2     | In9
```

So basically I want to extract rows only if there is one-is-to-many relationship between column 1 and column 2.

Like P3 only had 1 corresponding value in column 2, so it should not be extracted. However, since P1 and P2 had multiple values in column 2, the associated rows were extracted.

Can you please help me with a query in MySql to extract the above output.

Comment: i don't understand for requirement mine first thought was that you wanted a unique list from duplicated records.  But that is not want you want because P3 Int3 is excluded from the expected results.. besides P2 In9 is included which doesn't have a duplication

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery with count(distinct IntegId) in join

```
SELECT DISTINCT my_table.TestId, my_table.IntegId
FROM my_table 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT TestID, COUNT(DISTINCT IntegID) 
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY TestId 
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT IntegID) > 1
) T ON T.TestID = my_table.TestID
```

Comment: P2 have two distinct IntegID  .. is this condition that revolve the as many .. condition by the OP

Comment: @RaymondNijland    Saturday is the right day for a bit of relaxation .. (it happens to everyone to see the data only in part) .. anyway thanks ..

Comment: i don't like to give somebody unnecessary "criticism" about there answer and later find out their right and iám wrong.. i will admit iám was wrong.. Mine comment "This will not include P2 | In9 record" was possibly copied pasted to soon without thinking because off that other answer which is now editted..

Comment: @RaymondNijland  I understand very well your point of view and I really appreciate your behavior .. .. often you give very useful suggestions ..

Comment: @scaisEdge - I was playing with this approach and it kept getting overcomplicated because I wasn't using `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT()` -  Nice job and I relearned something I had forgot about.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table to itself to get distinct `IntegID` columns and then use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicate rows like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.TestID, t1.IntegID
FROM my_table t1
JOIN my_table t2 ON t2.TestID = t1.TestID AND t2.IntegID != t1.IntegID;
```

I think the above approach is probably the simplest and will give you the best performance but I like scaisEdge's answer above using `COUNT(DISTINCT...` so here's yet another approach using `IN` and selecting only the `TestID` rows you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TestID, IntegID
FROM my_table
WHERE TestID IN
(
    SELECT TestID
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY TestID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT IntegID) > 1
)
```

Sometimes it's nice to try a few approaches and see what works best with your indexes and other aspects of your application.  Cheers.

Comment: This will not include `P2 | In9` record

Comment: you're right, I overlooked the desired results - updated